# gcc version not compatible with progol software

Tags: gcc

I am using an ILP system named proGol which is not anymore state of the art; progol implementation has been in C though the syntax of coding is similar to prolog. However, I can run it on old machines with gcc version of 3.4.3. Such machines are very old and I need to run my code on new servers with gcc version on 4.6.3. When I do that, the software outputs segmentation error. I believe the problem is the gcc versions that are not compatible and progol itself probably can be run only on 32 bit processors. Does anyone know how I can adjust the gcc version of machine to older versions?

Comment: I'd make a guess that the old code modifies string constants (probably because a string literal is passed to a function as a `char *` and the function then modifies the string).  Such code was never portable; the version 4 GCC compilers no longer support the old `-fwriteable-strings` option (with one or two e's in the option).  Your main choices AFAICS are (1) fix proGol code so it does not modify string literals, or (2) rebuild the GCC 3.4.x compiler on the newer machine.  Long term, you'd be best off dealing with (1); short term, there's a chance that (2) seems simpler.

Comment: you comment was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I recently have to deal with this same error and I ended here looking for an answer since this is at this moment the first google result when someone looks for "progol segmentation fault".

Compiling progol using gcc-4.8 has worked for me. I just simply changed the gcc alias in the Makefile by 'gcc-4.8'.

I hope this could help someone.